# npm test unexpected behaviour on CircleCI

Tags: node.js, circleci, jestjs

Posting an issue I faced along with the answer, as aided by CircleCI's support.

I had setup tests and when run locally, they all ran and passed.
However when CircleCI was running them, there were errors.

The first was that `usage of let and const are not allowed outside of 'use strict' mode`.

I amended the culprit files, then re-built.
Then I got a weird error:
`Unexpected token {`

I could find nothing wrong with the code itself.

See below for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for contribubting to SO.  Please move the solution portion to an answer below (IIRC you should have enough reputation to do so.)

Comment: thanks for the pointer. only familiarising with the correct protocols now.

Answer (score 2):

CircleCI's support pointed me in the right direction.

It was due to mismatch between node version that CircleCI was using and the node version I was using locally (v8.1.0).

I solved it by creating a **circle.yml** file and inserting below code:

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 8.1.0
```